# Displaying LongBlob data as image

Tags: java, blob

I have the following code to read blob data & display the result as an image. But I'm getting the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response`.

```
while (rs2.next()) {
    Blob image = null;
    byte[] imgData = null;
    j++;
    qPaperOptions = rs2.getString(1);
    int qDetailId = rs2.getInt(2);
    image = rs2.getBlob(5);

    ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();
    // o.close();
    // imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
    // Blob cnt_data=rs2.getBlob("cimg.ctn_data");
    if (image != null) {
        // imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
        response.setContentType("image/gif");
        InputStream in = image.getBinaryStream();
        int length = (int) image.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            sout.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to resolve that error?

Comment: kindly share the DDL script of the table

Answer (score 0):

Which line is throwing the exception? In general the code looks correct.  Just a couple of ideas:
Could it be that you're iterating over this code twice (two results or more in the resultset)?   Also, try setting the contentType before getting the output stream.

Comment: in this line im getting errorServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();

Comment: Con you post the whole method that invokes this? Could it be that you're sending something to the response before trying to get the OutputStream?